# How to convert "/Date(1639580400000-0000)/" into the date time format in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, developer-tools

How to convert `Date(1639580400000-0000)` into the date time format in flutter dart..

`startDateTime`: `Date(1639580400000-0000)`,

i want to change this string into the date format
: `exp- (12-MAY-2023)`

I want to convert this string into the date format in the Flutter (dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function hope this will work for you

```dart
DateTime parseStringToDate(String input) {
  final RegExp dateRegex = RegExp(r"\/Date\((\d+)([+-]\d{4})\)\/");
  final match = dateRegex.firstMatch(input);

  if (match != null) {
    final timestamp = int.parse(match.group(1)!);
    final offset = match.group(2);
    final milliseconds = timestamp + (offset == "-0000" ? 0 : int.parse(offset!));

    return DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds, isUtc: true);
  }

  throw Exception("Invalid date format: $input");
}
```

you can checkout full code here
https://dartpad.dev/?id=4223a468a49f24a41f0282fb990718fb

Answer (score 0):

```dart
    changeDateFormat(date){
  RegExp? regex = RegExp(r'\d+');
  Match? match = regex.firstMatch(date);
  int timestamp = int.parse(match!.group(0).toString());

  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp, isUtc: true);
  var convertedDate = DateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(dateTime);
  return convertedDate;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

add this package ([intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)) to your pubspec.

```
String formatDate() {
  String input = "/Date(1639580400000-0000)/";
  
  int startIdx = input.indexOf("(");
  int endIdx = input.indexOf(")");
  
  String time = input.substring(startIdx+1,endIdx);

  int index = time.indexOf("-");

  if (index == -1) index = time.length;

  String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy').format(
      DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(time.substring(0, index))));

  return formattedDate;
}
```

[image: demo]